# remove a string between columns

Tags: regex, string, awk, sed

I am trying to remove text between two strings but keep all the data before and after the pattern. Example text that I am working with:

```
comp117_c0_seq1 len=214 path=[173:0-52 372:53-71 226:72-213]
comp143_c0_seq1 len=285 path=[263:0-226 490:227-284]
comp541_c0_seq1 len=230 path=[1:0-132 134:133-229]  gi|356502740|ref|XP_003520174.1| PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC100809655 [Glycine max]  1.30898e-39 68  76
```

So the objective is to remove the text starting at "len" and ending at " path = [...]". and keep all before and after that region of text. 
Would anyone have any suggestions. I would like the output to look like:

```
comp117_c0_seq1 
comp117_c0_seq1
comp541_c0_seq1 gi|356502740|ref|XP_003520174.1| PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC100809655 [Glycine max]  1.30898e-39 68  76
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This looks pretty easy

Comment: Do post the expected output as well

Comment: Hi, well i was trying awking out the first column and filling with pattern matches but I haven't learned sed too well, and I since the length of the pattern can vary I wasn't really sure out to do it.

Comment: simple enough `sed -E 's/len.*path[^]]*\]//'`

Comment: or since perl recognizes the non-greedy operator and given the shape of your data: `perl -pe 's/len.*?\]//'`

Comment: this is almost works, there is a second set a brackets in the third line of the example, and the sed matches there, but I still need to keep that text.

Comment: oh thank you! I was stuck on this for hours. the sed code worked. I need to study pattern matching more

Answer (score 2):

**Using `sed`**

```
$ sed -r 's/len[^]]*]//' input_file
comp117_c0_seq1 
comp143_c0_seq1 
comp541_c0_seq1   gi|356502740|ref|XP_003520174.1| PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC100809655 [Glycine max]  1.30898e-39 68  76
```

- `len` Matches `len`
- `[^]]*` Negated character class, matches anything other than a `]`.

  `*` Quantifier, ensures that *anything other than a `]`* is matched zero or more tiems
- `]` Matches the ending `]` at the end of `path`

---

**Using `awk`**

```
$ awk '{sub("len[^]]*]", "")}1' input
comp117_c0_seq1 
comp143_c0_seq1 
comp541_c0_seq1   gi|356502740|ref|XP_003520174.1| PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC100809655 [Glycine max]  1.30898e-39 68  76
```

- `sub(ere, repl[, in ])` Substitute  the string `repl` in place of the first instance of
               the extended regular expression `ERE`in string in  and  return
               the  number  of substitutions.
- `1` Always true. `awk` takes the default action to print the entire record.

Answer (score 1):

From your example input and outputs, it looks like you want to remove everything from `len` to the next `]`. Here goes (that's BSD/Mac sed):

```
sed -E 's/len[^]]*\]//'
```

Meaning: replace `len` and every character that is not a `]`, and then the `]`. This stops at the first `]` encountered. This is because sed is greedy. `perl` knows better:

```
perl -pe 's/len.*?\]//'
```

`*?` is non-greedy operator, so it only eats whatever the next token does not want.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with sed:

```
cat file | sed -e 's/(^.*)len=.*path=\[[^\]*\](.*)$/\1\2/'
```

I may need to revise this when you post your expected output though.

Comment: ok thank you, I added the expected output and will give this a shot. Thank you for your patience, I've just started learning programming.

Comment: You are having unecessary usage of `cat` in the solution

Comment: you don't really need the group capture

Comment: also, the `\[.*\]` is greedy, so when there are more `]` after the path declaration, the whole thing is eaten by this wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
comp117_c0_seq1 len=214 path=[173:0-52 372:53-71 226:72-213]
comp143_c0_seq1 len=285 path=[263:0-226 490:227-284]
comp541_c0_seq1 len=230 path=[1:0-132 134:133-229]  gi|356502740|ref|XP_003520174.1| PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC100809655 [Glycine max]  1.30898e-39 68  76
```

Perl:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -lne 'print "$1$2" if /^(\w+)\slen=\d+\sp
ath=\[[^\]]+?\](.*)$/'
comp117_c0_seq1
comp143_c0_seq1
comp541_c0_seq1  gi|356502740|ref|XP_003520174.1| PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC100809655 [Glycine max]  1.30898e-39 68  76
```

Or,

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -lne 'print if s/len[^]]+\] *//'
comp117_c0_seq1 
comp143_c0_seq1 
comp541_c0_seq1 gi|356502740|ref|XP_003520174.1| PREDICTED: uncharacterized protein LOC100809655 [Glycine max]  1.30898e-39 68  76
```